# GRPC vs RAW QUERY

Tags: node.js, microservices, grpc, sequelize-typescript

Is it OK to use raw queries between two different services. I believe we should always go for GRPC in such cases but some of my colleagues say it is easy to make raw queries hence we do it. I doubt it as it is not a suitable solution according to me.Please comment your views.

Suppose I had two services, User and Admin . I believe if I have to fetch any data from user to admin or vice versa I should always GRPC.

Comment: Doesn't using raw queries break isolation and increase coupling?